# java serialize transient elements

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist, transient

am preparing myselg for some java t and I see something interesting in the java code:

in the ArrayList class I can see this :

```
  /**
     * The array buffer into which the elements of the ArrayList are stored.
     * The capacity of the ArrayList is the length of this array buffer.
     */
    private transient Object[] elementData;
```

so how is the list serializable is the array holding the data is tdefined as transient:?

Do they use some trick we can not see like bridge methods, fields or similar..

Thnxs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ArrayList uses [readObject() and writeObject()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) for serialization.